# I need the complete compile zxing source code

Tags: android, zxing

Can any one help me where I can find the complete compile zxing barcode scanersource code without install apk file? I see all tutorials which install apk file.

This code does not work fine. Please help me.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        Button scanner = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanner);
        scanner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }

        });

        Button scanner2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanner2);
        scanner2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }

        });

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Log.e("onCreate", "Scanner Not Found", anfe);
    }

 }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" +  
          format , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
            toast.show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Scan was Cancelled!",         
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: you're not "compiling"the zxing source code... please be careful with your terminology.

Comment: the how can i make application which scan barcode?

Comment: You can do a svn checkout of http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout to get the source code for zxing.

Comment: "this code not work".  Imagine I told you "my car does not work.  Please tell me what is wrong".  What would your answer be?  Now if I tell you my car does not start.  It has fuel but when I turn the key, nothing happens.  I do not get the red ignition light on the dashboard.  Now how would you answer?

Comment: i fount this url but it says install zing on ur mobile 1st how do i change this code so its not install directly use it zxing barcode scanner n application? http://uwudamith.wordpress.com/tag/read-barcode-using-android-camera/

Comment: Providing that you comply with the Apache license, download the Zxing source code and include the relevant parts in your app.

Comment: how? please give me any example

Comment: You are obviously trying to run before you can walk.  If you don't know how to download source code or how to add it to your app, then Stackoverflow is not for you.  Time to read some introduction to programming tutorials and Android.

Comment: just tell me barcode give scanning result only when internet connected? or is work fine when no internet connection available??

Comment: Did you even read the first paragraph of the Zxing webpage? http://code.google.com/p/zxing/  Trust me and take my advice.  You have a lot of learning to do before you can be successful with what you are trying to do.

Comment: <quote>Imagine I told you "my car does not work. Please tell me what is wrong". What would your answer be?</quote> - Quite obviously, the correct answer would be "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" - Sorry, couldn't resist ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Ant http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
2. Run > cmd
3. > cd (your extracted ant directory)
4. > ant -f (your Zxing source code directory)/core/build.xml
5. go to (Zxing source code dir)/core/ and move the core.jar to your (android project)/libs
6. Right click your Zxing project in eclipse > Properties > Java Build Path
7. Libraries tab > Add JARs and select that core.jar under your project

Now try

Comment: what is your Zxing Surce directry/core/build.xml?  is inside Ant zip file??

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\My Documents\Downloads\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apa
che-ant-1.8.4>ant-fzxing-2.1/core/build.xml

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\My Documents\Downloads\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4>   from this i go from cmd

Comment: yes i did all u say add core file in libs and add in  jars so now my this example http://uwudamith.wordpress.com/tag/read-barcode-using-android-camera/  is working correctly????

Comment: when i ren application on simulator and press scan buton application is stop unexpectedly